# Wordpress Multi-Step Product Search

Tags: plugins, search, woocommerce-offtopic, forms

I'm looking for advice on what would be the best way to create a multi-step product search, which could (potentially) then pull from WooCommerce, though that's not mandatory. Does anyone know of any plugins which are designed to do this already, or would it need to be custom built?

An example would be if you were search for a car, you could ask the customer what colour would they like, hit next, how large an engine, hit next, maybe 2/3 extra questions, then submit to query the product catalogue for products with those attributes.

Much appreciated, I'm very much a Wordpress newbie!

Thanks

Comment: I know this is old, but for future reference to other visitors, I was looking for the exact same thing and the answer above did not suite the needs, so I Googled for a while and found this: [http://troll-winner.ru/questionnaire-filter/](http://troll-winner.ru/questionnaire-filter/)

Answer (score 1):

This plugin might help you achieve what you are looking for.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-step-form/

Comment: Thanks very much for that. That's exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for forms-wise, I just need a way to have it query the database with the results! Hopefully that's not too difficult.

Comment: I think the plugin sends email by default. You can try to see it they also have support for database saving or if they have any hook to do this.